При попытке засунуть в Dbeaver любой селект в CTE, через with...as() выдает ошибку синтаксиса, при этом сам внутренний селект работает нормально
Обучаюсь sql и дошел до момента с общими табличными выражениями (CTE), и при попытке написать даже самое простое выражение через with ... as ()   Dbeaver выдает ошибку - SQL Error [42601]: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса в конце
Позиция: 53
Позиция ошибки: line: 3 pos: 52
Для примера беру самый простой запрос:
with filtered_category as (
select * from film f
)

При этом отдельно этот селект отрабатывается, пустых строк нет, пробовал и с ; в конце и без, пишу запрос из обучения и вообще любой селект через WITH и сразу ошибка, хотя в обучающем видео всё ОК. Может кто сталкивался и может подсказать, что не так?

А где продолжение запроса? После конструкции with должен идти select

Ошибка вам говорит о том, что у вас ошибка в синтаксите.
В вашем случае, это отсутствует select для with
with filtered_category as ( select * from film f )
select * from filtered_category;

т.е. в with вы получаете одну таблицу и ниже выбираете уже из нее нужные данные

Спасибо, да как то не понял сразу, что без второго селекта запрос не будет выдавать данные!
